# In Einstein notation, why do basis vectors have lower indices?

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

For example, the vector V can be written as
$V=V^\mu\hat{e}_\mu$.

Why does the basis vector have covariant lower indices?

Comment: It is essentially a matter of convention which indices are upper and which indices are lower. The important matter, independent of convention, is that the basis vectors transform *oppositely* to coordinates. The rough intuition is that the vector $V$ doesn't care about any particular basis or set of coordinates. Hence, $V^{\mu}$ should transform oppositely to $e_{\mu}$ to leave $V$ invariant. Did you mean to ask why do the basis vectors $e_{\mu}$ satisfy the transformation law that it does? Certainly tangent vectors and compotents have definite transformation laws, independent of convention.

Comment: Why not? Are you asking why he chose the lower indices over the higher indices or why he chose to index it?

Comment: There is no objective reason why upper indices are upper and lower indices are lower, kind of like how there is no objective reason why electrons have negative charge and protons positive. The importance lies in making them opposite one another, not which is which. As for why basis vectors have covariant indices, they clearly transform covariantly, as you may check yourself.

Comment: Vectors are contravariant, dual vectors are covariant.  So why are basis vectors somehow special and are covariant?

Comment: @Benighted Thanks.  If you make that comment into an answer I will checkmark it.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Yes I wasn't asking about the particular choice of lower indices, but rather why it was chosen to be opposite of the components.  Now I understand due to the transformation laws.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest explanation is because you're supposed to add the terms of a linear combination. Since the coordinates of the vector have upper index the base has to be indexed with lower index.

You can also understand this by the fact that the base is covariant. This may be easier to see if you consider vectors as tuples instead, that is you write $V^\nu = V^{\mu}e_\mu^\nu$ (in fact the basis works as a linear map from tuples to vectors).

Comment: Why does the e_\mu^\nu have an upper and lower index of its a basis vector? What does it mean?